# List all products with a certain attribute value in Magento

Tags: magento, content-management-system

What I am trying to do is add some links below the layered navigation in Magento on the Product Listing Page. I have the layered navigation working nicely but I have some other groups of items that I would like to have listed on click of a link. These items can be identified by a custom attribute that I added. In example a featured_product list.